# Exponential values in graphing varibles in Netlogo

Tags: variables, netlogo, exponential

I am writing a water model. For every water use salinity and logging are being updated.I have set different typologies for farmer to use surface and groundwater as a consequence of their water use they will face logging and salinity.Variables of logging and salinity jumped from very small values to exponentially large values as ticks go up. I just want them to stay under 10 in 200 ticks.
Below are the codes i have provided. I hope readers  won't mind me putting details. Here is interface of the model [image]
Thanks

```
globals [TW  well-depth ]
Breed [farmers farmer]
farmers-own [ WA SW FW WR WD dws Logging salinity benefit-out]
patches-own [GW wtd ] ;water table depth and Groundwater
to setup
   clear-all
    setup-farmers
    ask patches [ ifelse random 3 = 0 [
    set WTD depth-WT + random-float 1
    set GW Ground-water + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
    set pcolor blue
     ]

     [ set WTD depth-WT + 5 + random-float 5
       set GW Ground-water + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
       set pcolor red]
        ]

  reset-ticks
end
to setup-farmers

create-farmers num-farmers [move-to one-of patches
                             set shape "person"
                             set sw surface-water + random 100.0
                             set dws random 100 + distance-from-water-source
  SET WA  (sw / dws) + sum [gw] of patches in-radius 1 
  set logging  0.005 * dws +  0.5 * wtd
  set salinity   .05 * dws + 0.5 * wtd
  set wd minwater-req + random-float 6.5
  set benefit-out 0
  ask patches in-radius 1 [set pcolor green]
  set color Brown
  if WTD = 0 [stop]
]
end
to go

  ask farmers [
   watering-decisions
  update-water
  ]

  tick

end
to watering-decisions 
  if watering-decision = "zero-intelligence"
  [ ifelse SW > WD [use-sw
                           set-wtd 
                           set logging logging + logging / wtd 
                           Set salinity salinity + salinity + 0.5 * wtd
                           Set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity) ]


                           [ ifelse (sw > 0.6 * WD) and  (sw < 0.75 * WD) [ifelse random 3 = 1 [use-Gw
                                                                           set wtd wtd + .01 + random-float 0.005
                                                                           set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                           set salinity salinity + 5 * (salinity / wtd) ; scale up values 0.5*10, 0.005* 10 
                                                                           set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity) ]
                                                                           [Use-sw
                                                                            set wtd  wtd + ( 0.01 + random-float 0.0005)
                                                                            set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                            Set salinity salinity + salinity + 0.5 * wtd
                                                                            Set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity)]]     
                                                                                       [ifelse (SW >= 0.5 * WD) and (sw <= 0.6 * WD)
                                                                                                    [ifelse random 1 = 0 [use-Gw
                                                                                                      set wtd wtd - .01 + random-float 0.05 
                                                                                                      set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                                                       Set salinity salinity + 5 * (salinity / wtd)
                                                                                                       Set benefit-out benefit-out + 100  / 1.5 * (logging + salinity) ]                                                                                                         [use-sw
                                                                                                           set wtd wtd + .01 + random-float 0.005                                                                                                               set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                                                           set salinity salinity + 5 * (salinity / wtd)
                                                                                                           set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity)]]
                                                                                                              [ifelse (SW >= 0.25 * WD) and (sw <= 0.3 * WD)
                                                                                                                [ ifelse random 3 = 1[use-sw
                                                                                                                  set wtd wtd + .001 + random-float 0.005
                                                                                                                   set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                                                                   set salinity salinity + 5 * (salinity / wtd)
                                                                                                                   set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity)]
                                                                                                                    [use-Gw
                                                                                                                      set wtd wtd - .1 + random-float 0.005
                                                                                                                      set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                                                                      set salinity salinity + 5 * (salinity / wtd)
                                                                                                                      Set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity)]]
                                                                                                                      [ if sw = 0  [use-gw
                                                                                                                                      set wtd wtd - 0.5 + random-float 0.005
                                                                                                                                      set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                                                                                      set salinity salinity + 0.5 * (salinity / wtd)
                                                                                                                                      Set benefit-out benefit-out + 100 / (logging + salinity) ]]]]]]
to use-GW
  set gw gw - random-float 1
end
to use-SW
  set sw sw - random-float 1
end
to  Update-water

end

to set-wtd
  set wtd wtd  + ( 0.01 + random-float 0.005)
  ask patches  in-radius 1 [ set wtd [wtd] of myself]

 end
```

Comment: If you need to put an artificial limit (like 'if the answer to this equation gives me more than 10, then make it 10') to avoid an equation giving you back unreasonably large numbers, then the most likely problem is that your equations are not an accurate description of the system being modelled. Your best option is to put a lot of `print` statements into your code so you can try and identify where the equations are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I will see if this can help.